# How can mitigate a tab click?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a tab group:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Programmes" tabIcon="icon-programmes"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" (ionSelect)="studioCheck()" tabTitle="Studio" tabIcon="icon-studio"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Library" tabIcon="icon-library"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="icon-profile"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

When a user clicks the second tab ('Studio'), I need to check if they have access to it yet.  If they do, great, if they don't, I want to show a toast notification and load the first tab.

How can I do this?

I thought a `return false` would suffice on `studioCheck()`, but it does not.

Typescript:

```
  studioCheck() {
    console.log('Studio visited');

    // Grab studio selected level
    this.storage.get('studio_level').then((val) => {
      console.log('Storage queried');
      if(val) {
        console.log('Level ID: ', val);
        return true;
      } else {
        // No level selected
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Please choose a programme in order to use the Studio',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });
        toast.present();
        this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

I thought that perhaps the `ionSelect` doesn't wait for the asynchronous `storage.get` call, so I just did a `return false;` at the top of the function, but that does the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

adjust view like this

```
<ion-tabs #tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Programmes" tabIcon="icon-programmes"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" (ionSelect)="studioCheck()" tabTitle="Studio" tabIcon="icon-studio"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Library" tabIcon="icon-library"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="icon-profile"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

and then in controller:

```
export class MyPage {
    @ViewChild("tabs") public tabs: Tabs;
    ...

    studioCheck() {
        console.log('Studio visited');

        // Grab studio selected level
        this.storage.get('studio_level').then((val) => {
            console.log('Storage queried');
            if(val) {
                console.log('Level ID: ', val);
                return true;
            } else {
                // No level selected
                let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: 'Please choose a programme in order to use the Studio',
                  duration: 3000,
                  position: 'top'
                });
                toast.present();
                this.tabs.select(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## Explanation

- in order to switch tab in code, you must grap instance of `Tabs` and call `select` on that.
- keep in mind that `ionSelect` is emitted when the tab is selected, so return value is ignored.
- due to `this.storage.get`, your code is async, so `return false;` do not leave `studioCheck` method anyway

Comment: This still has the same outcome.  The reason being is that `this.storage.get` is async, so the tab switches without waiting for the storage call.

Comment: well yeah tab switches, but it should return  back to the first tab pretty quickly in case it is restricted..thats the purpose of "this.tabs.select(0)"

Comment: It fails because the tab I'm switching to runs, which I want to prevent, as there is data in storage it requires which doesn't exist. I know I can add logic in that page to prevent that happening, but I was hoping for a way to not open the tab at all, rather than to open and then close it

Comment: hm, there is "enabled" attribute on ion-tab, but I guess it is not an option for you since you want tab to be clickable. You will need your own implementation of ion-tabs, there are source code available where you can get an inspiration: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/tabs/tabs.ts